# How to test universal linking in development phase for iOS 9?

Tags: ios, ios9, ios-universal-links

After **development** of universal link in app, how to cross check in the development phase for it's correctness so that it can be properly deployed for **production** i.e live .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your device and not simulator. You can send a Universal link to your email and click it to make sure it works.